# Changing datatables.net structure dynamically

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using [Datatables](http://datatables.net) grid to show data from different datasources dynamically at server-side through AJAX.
These datasources have different column names and quantities.

Whats the better way to change datatables configuration on the fly.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "dynamically". For example, would you be fine with using different tabs for the different datasources?

Comment: The best way should the columns be informed by the backend, so the table could be rebuilt with the new columns.

Comment: I doubt that datatables supports rerendering of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am doing what you've suggested now to populate the table header dynamically which are returned from server response prior to initialise the data table using datatables grid.

The possible pseudo-code can be:

```
function initDataTable() {
    var theadSetup = loadColumnSetup(); // load thead setup from server
    // construct thead which are required to initialise a datatable
    constructTableHead(theadSetup); // manipulate TH elements here
    $('.dataTable').dataTable( {
        aaData: dataSrc, // may also be retrieved from server
        // other settings...
    } );
}
```

Comment: Your loadColumnSetup() should receive a param, so it could return different column structures from server, each one supporting respective data source.